# WinDbg - compare a string argument with a string from memory

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, low-level

I need to compare a string, passed as an argument to *WinDbg* with a string from memory. How can this be achieved?

For example, the string is located in a specific offset within the loaded PE. So, I can easily read the string by executing `da /c 100 <addr>`.
But, how can I use this string, to compare it with `arg1`, in a *WinDbg* script, using `.if`? (and `$SPAT()`, I guess)

I was trying to read the output of the `da` command into an *Alias* or a *User-Defined Register*, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't recall a way to get WinDbg's command line. You can write an extensions that does that, though.

Comment: @conio what do you you mean by an extention? Isn't there a way just to read a string from a specific address? (maybe using MASM/@@c++ syntax) I just think it's highly unlikely that such a trivial task is impossible to perform using WinDbg scripting

Comment: @ThomasWeller I just want to compare a passed argument, which holds a string, with a string stored in in a specific offset in the loaded PE. Wildcards aren't important here.

Comment: @conio: there is `-c` which can be used to execute commands. See my answer below. Not an arbitrary command line, but something under your control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a string to an alias using `as /c`:

```
0:012> as /c Hello .printf "%ma", 06130000
0:012> .echo @"${Hello}"
Hello world
```

You can then use `$spat()` on it:

```
0:012> ? $spat(@"${Hello}","*ell*")
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000000`00000001
0:012> ? $spat(@"${Hello}","x*")
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000`00000000
```

To control the pattern from the command line, set another alias using the `-c` command line switch:

```
windbg -c "as Pattern *ell*"

// this line is from the command line argument
0:006> as Pattern *ell*

0:006> .dvalloc 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 04610000
0:006> ea 04610000 "Hello world"
0:006> as /c Hello .printf "%ma", 04610000
0:006> .echo ${Pattern}
*ell*
0:006> .echo ${Hello}
Hello world
0:006> ? $spat(@"${Hello}", @"${Pattern}")
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
```

Comment: Almost trivial, isn't it?

Comment: definitely.. ;_;

Comment: Why `as /c Name .printf "%m(s)u/a", Address` instead of simply `as /m(s)u/a Name Address`?

Comment: @conio: indeed. I had problems with quotes at first, but that might work as well now

Comment: I wish this could be used for Kernel mode, this is user-mode only. My alternative is to hijack the memory space of a previously allocated qint.

Answer (score 2):

a javascript like this can be used too

```
function log(instr) {
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(instr + "\n");
}
function initializeScript(){
    return [new host.namedModelParent(foo, "Debugger.Models.Process")];
}
class foo {
    Init(comparand)    {
        var peb             = host.currentProcess.Environment.EnvironmentBlock;
        var cmdlinebuff     = peb.ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Buffer;
        var cmdline         = host.memory.readWideString(cmdlinebuff);
        var progname        = cmdline.slice(0, cmdline.indexOf(" "));
        var argname1        = cmdline.slice(cmdline.indexOf(" ")+1);
        log (progname);
        log (argname1);
        if(comparand==argname1)        {
            log ( "argument matches with comparand");
        }else{
            log("argument does not match with comparand ");
        }       
    }
}
```

and run it like this

```
C:\>cdb -c ".load jsprovider;.scriptload c:\cmdln.js" calc my_1337_cmdline

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.load jsprovider;.scriptload c:\cmdln.js'
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'c:\cmdln.js'

0:000> dx @$curprocess.Init("my_1337")
calc
my_1337_cmdline
argument does not match with comparand
@$curprocess.Init("my_1337")

0:000> dx @$curprocess.Init("my_1337_cmdline")
calc
my_1337_cmdline
argument matches with comparand
@$curprocess.Init("my_1337_cmdline")
0:000>
```

instead of literal string if you need to pass an address you can do that too

```
function log(instr) { 
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(instr + "\n"); 
}
function initializeScript(){
    return[new host.namedModelParent(foo, "Debugger.Models.Process")];
}
class foo {
    cmpCmdln(addrtostr)    {
        var peb     = host.currentProcess.Environment.EnvironmentBlock;
        var clnbuf  = peb.ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Buffer;
        var cmdln   = host.memory.readWideString(clnbuf);
        var arg1    = cmdln.slice(cmdln.indexOf(" ")+1);
        var teststr = host.memory.readString(addrtostr);
        if(teststr.slice(0,arg1.length)===arg1)        {
            log("Deal With Success : " + teststr);
        }else{
            log("Deal with failure : " + teststr);
        }       
    }
}
```

load jsprovider , load script and run like

```
0:000> du @@c++((@$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine.Buffer))
001d20a4  "calc !This"

0:000> dx @$curprocess.cmpCmdln(0x52004d)
Deal With Success : !This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
$
@$curprocess.cmpCmdln(0x52004d)

0:000> dx @$curprocess.cmpCmdln(0x52005d)
Deal with failure : nnot be run in DOS mode.
$
@$curprocess.cmpCmdln(0x52005d)
```