# Windbg conditional memory search

Tags: debugging, windbg, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I need to set breakpoint in debugger windbg when address in register points to memory block with some pattern and that pattern is not fixed to offset
something like

```
bp ws2_32!sendto "j s @rdx @rdx+100 53 65 6e 64 g"
```

how to write this condition properly?
so i need to break on sendto only when in range of address inside **rdx and rdx+100** there is this pattern **53 65 6e 64**

```
bp ws2_32!sendto ".if(s @rdx @rdx+100 53 65 6e 64) == 0 { g }" error too
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `s` does not make up a valid condition. It either prints a result or not.

Preparation for the demonstration

```
2:007> .dvalloc 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 003b0000

2:007> eb 003b0000 53 65 6e 64

2:007> db 003b0000 L10
003b0000  53 65 6e 64 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Send............
```

A test using `s`

```
2:007> s-a 003b0000 L100 "Send"
003b0000  53 65 6e 64 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Send............

2:007> s-a 003b0000 L100 "Test"
```

You can use `.foreach` on the output of `s`. It will run the command for every word in the output, which is too much:

```
2:007> .foreach (output {s-a 003b0000 L100 "Send"}) { .echo "found" }
found
found
found
found
[...]
```

So let's use the fact that `s` has a special option for outputting just the address

```
2:007> .foreach (output {s-[1]a 003b0000 L100 "Send"}) { .echo "found" }
found
```

I can't repro with your breakpoint at the moment, but it should look like

```
bp ws2_32!sendto ".foreach (output {s-[1]a @rdx L100 "Send"}) { g }"
```

This should also work when searching for bytes instead of ASCII string and with a register instead of an address

```
2:007> r eax = 003b0000

2:007> .foreach (output {s-[1]b @eax L100 53 65 6e 64}) { .echo "found" }
found
```

Comment: thanks i have also question, this foreach works but for some reason condition breakpoint always triggers even with no pattern,  `bp ws2_32!sendto ".foreach /ps 100 (output {s-b @rdx L100 07 00 00 } ) { .echo 'hit'; g }"` it looks if bp doesnt wait for foreach to complete and always gets TRUE i tried workaround like this `bp ws2_32!sendto ".foreach /ps 100 (output {s-b @rdx L100 07 00 00 } ) { .break }; g"` but instead it always misses breakpoint and foreach function not getting executed because of 'g'

Comment: @andrey2003: yes, the observation is correct: the breakpoint does not have a condition, so it always triggers, meaning that it will always search memory and always loop over the results and continue when something was found. And you want the opposite... damn!

Comment: Feel free to unaccept the answer for the moment

Comment: I guess you need a freaky combination of `$spat()` and aliases as desribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434142/480982

Comment: I got this idea i come up with this https://pastebin.com/btfCcPnu

But how to combine aliasing and bp? something like this:

https://pastebin.com/spUCMNUF

Comment: i get no "BREAK?" or "FAILED?" so last part with if and spatt not getting executed and seems it is treated as part of alias from documentation of aS with /c option i see `CommandString
Specifies the commands whose outputs become the alias equivalent. This string can include any number of commands that are separated by semicolons.` how can i put this in bp statement?

Comment: I managed do it using file so i created file `c:\dbg\scripting\bp_pattern1.txt` after i set breakpoint like this `bp ws2_32!sendto "$$<c:\\dbg\\scripting\\bp_pattern1.txt"` , the actual file script is here if anyone want as example https://pastebin.com/bWpDyRmA